# Using processing 3.0 render pipeline with a custom projection matrix

Tags: processing, render, projection-matrix

My goal is only to use the current processing PGraphcsOpenGL rendering pipeline replacing the camera or projection transformation matrix. The current code returns me strange results. I can't understand how processing is multiplying matrices internally or even if this is possible to achieve what I want this way.

All closest [references](https://processing.org/discourse/beta/num_1273419930.html) I found are not opengl compatible. Another solution would probably be decomposing this matrix to extract camera parameters and set the camera object every frame. I couldn't make it work. But my first attempts increased the number of lines considerably.

```
PMatrix3D p; 

void setup() {
  size(600, 400, P3D);

  p = new PMatrix3D(
    5.400566, 0.519709, -4.3888016, 193.58757, 
    5.284709, -9.016302, 3.312224, 266.927, 
    0.012042404, 7.253584E-5, 0.0084899925, 1.0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1);

  p.invert();
}

void draw() {

  float x = map(mouseX, 0, width, -200, 200);
  float z = map(mouseY, 0, height, -150, 150);


  ((PGraphicsOpenGL) g).camera.set(p);
  //?
  //((PGraphicsOpenGL) g).modelview.set(p);
  //((PGraphicsOpenGL) g).projection.set(p);


  background(20);
  lights();
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  translate(x, 0, z);
  box(100);
}
```

**EDIT**
Below is a code where I multiply each vertex directly with the matrix. Results are quite different from the previous code.
Processing has its own native rendering pipeline including a camera, lighting, shaders, etc. I didn't want to build a new shader just because I am not being able to set the camera matrix. However this is what I am doing now for my project. And by doing so I drop my framerate by half.Terrible.

```
PMatrix3D p; 

void setup() {
  size(600, 400, P3D);

  p = new PMatrix3D(
    5.400566, 0.519709, -4.3888016, 193.58757, 
    5.284709, -9.016302, 3.312224, 266.927, 
    0.012042404, 7.253584E-5, 0.0084899925, 1.0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1);

  //p.invert();
}

void draw() {

  float x = map(mouseX, 0, width, -500, 500);
  float z = map(mouseY, 0, height, -500, 500);

  //((PGraphicsOpenGL) g).camera.set(p);
  //((PGraphicsOpenGL) g).modelview.set(p);
  //((PGraphicsOpenGL) g).projection.set(p);

  background(50);
  lights();
  //translate(width/2, height/2);
    translate(x, 0, z);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(1);
  //box(100);
  myBox(true);

}

void myBox(boolean multiplyed) {
  float side = 10;
  float h = side/2;
  /* cube verteces
  -----5------
  --1-------6-
  --------2---
  -----7------
  --3-------8-
  --------4---
  */
  PVector [] vtx = {
    new PVector (-h, -h, -h), 
    new PVector (+h, -h, -h),
    new PVector (-h, +h, -h),
    new PVector (+h, +h, -h),
    new PVector (-h, -h, +h), 
    new PVector (+h, -h, +h),
    new PVector (-h, +h, +h),
    new PVector (+h, +h, +h),
  };

  strokeWeight(5);
  for(PVector v : vtx){
    if(multiplyed){
      PVector result = new PVector();
      PMatrix3D mat = p;
      mat.mult(v, result);
      stroke(#ff0000);
      point(result.x/result.z ,result.y/result.z) ;
    }else{
      point(v.x,v.y,v.z);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say you couldn't make it work? What do you expect this code to do? What does it do instead?

Comment: Well, if I take each vertex from a cube (considering cube is just a simple example of a much more complex object) and multiply it by the presented matrix I get a very different result than when using the code I have so far.

I am pretty sure I am just not being able to use graphicsOpenGl function to setup a camera matrix, which is my goal.

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of research on it and found out this about `OpenGL`:

> "The renderer class, `PGraphicsOpenGL`, exposes a function that can be used for that purpose, called `textureSapling(int mode)`, where mode can take the values 2 (nearest), 3 (linear), 4 (bilinear) and 5 (trilinear).

Research taken from https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Advanced-OpenGL, edited by technosalon.

Because you only have those options, try changing your `mode` variable to a higher number to see if that works.